# Cannot capture javafx CheckBoxTableCell CellEditEvent

Tags: javafx-2

I have defined a CheckBoc TableColumn as

```
@FXML    private TableColumn<Batch, Boolean> sltd;
```

And have defined the CellValueFactory & CellFactory

```
sltd.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Batch, Boolean>("pr"));
sltd.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(sltd));
```

My problem is i am not able to capture the edit column event for the checkbox. I use the following code:

```
sltd.setOnEditStart(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Batch, Boolean>>() {
    @Override 
    public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Batch, Boolean> t) {
        //System.out.println("CheckBox clicked.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the check boxes in the CheckBoxTableCell invoke the startEdit(...) method on the table.

The only thing that can happen in an edit is that the boolean property of one of the items in the table changes from true to false, or vice versa. So you can check for this just by listening directly to those boolean properties.

If you want a single listener that will catch changes to any of the properties, you can create an observableList with an "extractor" and register a list change listener with the list. This looks like:

```
ObservableList<Batch> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Callback<Batch, Observable[]>() {
  @Override
  public Observable[] call(Batch batch) {
    return new Observable[] { batch.prProperty() } ;
  }
}
// populate items
table.setItems(items);

items.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Batch>() {
  @Override
  public void onChanged(Change<? extends Batch> change) {
    while (change.hasNext()) {
      if (change.wasUpdated()) {
        System.out.println("Item at "+change.getFrom()+" changed value");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i really didnt understand the callback part.

Comment: @James Besides the API is there more info someplace with regards to the extractor callback ?

Comment: There is very little documentation on the extractors. My understanding is that if you define an extractor (a Callback from the element type of the list to an array of Observables), then when an element is added to the list the callback is invoked and listeners are registered with each of the returned Observables. If those observables change, then the changes are propagated as update events to the list itself. So in this case, when a Batch item is added to the list, a listener is registered with its prProperty. If that changes, it causes an update event on the list.